# Opencv Error:(-215)

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing this simple code but this is showing error saying size.width>0&&size.height>0 in function imshow()`enter code here`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Desktop/x.jpg',0)
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the path is wrong

Comment: it means that `img` is probably `None` or invalid as it failed to load your `jpg`

Comment: `C:/Users/Desktop` is not a valid path (unless you have a user named Desktop)

Comment: Do you need to replace `'/'`by `'\'` or by `'\\'`?

Comment: Thank you! i have replace '/' by '\\' but still error continues. i think that error is comming due to imshow function.

Comment: can you paste the code with the complete error statement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows, write path name as:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\x.jpg', 0)
```

to load the image correctly.

Comment: Thank you! i have replace '/' by '\\' but still error continues. i think that error is comming due to imshow function.